# How to offset and fill extra tick labels with same size boxes

Tags: pgfplots, boxes, ticks

in the code provided below, I wanted the `extra x tick` labels to show up better by including an opacity filled box around the text so that the text shows up better with the boxes above the x-axis and of equal size.  Can you help me accomplish this task?

Here is the code that I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
0   0.10206670000
1   0.09905792000
2   0.06677074000
3   0.02062632000
4   0.00180701100
5   0.00002654813
6   0.00003744502
7   0.00004003021
8   0.00002708582
9   0.00002307745
10  0.00003643514
11  0.00004641169
12  0.00004744656
13  0.00003082966
14  0.00003775425
15  0.00008938722
16  0.00013548500
17  0.00015285560
18  0.00014095270
19  0.00011902230
20  0.00011660580
21  0.00007680599
22  0.00004823680
23  0.00007528155
24  0.00012932520
25  0.00014396080
26  0.00009415951
27  0.00006138856
28  0.00007132459
29  0.00007670367
30  0.00008301680
31  0.00010145180
32  0.00015893710
33  0.00023337950
34  0.00027370890
35  0.00026749480
36  0.00023144810
37  0.00019094270
38  0.00017619290
39  0.00021714180
40  0.00021507670
41  0.00017499700
42  0.00010223320
43  0.00005734080
44  0.00013067910
45  0.00012689820
46  0.00013588770
47  0.00012935150
48  0.00011225500
49  0.00013967980
50  0.00020306920
51  0.00015598630
52  0.00002845892
53  0.00022813320
54  0.00034332840
55  0.00035366590
56  0.00029860290
57  0.00014724470
58  0.00027776550
59  0.00057385510
60  0.00068391180
61  0.00078191920
62  0.00071762080
63  0.00050012280
64  0.00037338890
65  0.00026202910
66  0.00018668800
67  0.00026404690
68  0.00039164640
69  0.00043375420
70  0.00037268550
71  0.00027936230
72  0.00035795920
73  0.00043023800
74  0.00035592530
75  0.00014477900
76  0.00014335430
77  0.00034946590
78  0.00039751280
79  0.00037979610
80  0.00036745820
81  0.00030650400
82  0.00033379680
83  0.00016950630
84  0.00015314110
85  0.00021218250
86  0.00026757990
87  0.00029684980
88  0.00021983490
89  0.00021712020
90  0.00030226340
91  0.00027616690
92  0.00022501960
93  0.00022717420
94  0.00034574880
95  0.00047935380
96  0.00044816540
97  0.00036174180
98  0.00029356430
99  0.00039447840
100 0.00048994890
101 0.00040866000
102 0.00020533350
103 0.00013832120
104 0.00024108370
105 0.00027145800
106 0.00029451660
107 0.00035364680
108 0.00033782880
109 0.00031596130
110 0.00032908740
111 0.00040961120
112 0.00051725500
113 0.00055076700
114 0.00059070610
115 0.00057095880
116 0.00043408060
117 0.00048303870
118 0.00086490710
119 0.00106591000
120 0.00099537530
121 0.00092025930
122 0.00057619370
123 0.00019065650
124 0.00029203030
125 0.00037294010
126 0.00036201760
127 0.00030034640
128 0.00028138560
129 0.00026080750
130 0.00022018530
131 0.00017211250
132 0.00020692040
133 0.00023723030
134 0.00033711070
135 0.00045136930
136 0.00060931720
137 0.00059772130
138 0.00039938640
139 0.00027773650
140 0.00018083480
141 0.00022519290
142 0.00045445990
143 0.00066760330
144 0.00069811000
145 0.00057934330
146 0.00047084580
147 0.00034041880
148 0.00027271540
149 0.00025995150
150 0.00031026220
151 0.00037575350
152 0.00053989100
153 0.00059155420
154 0.00045315920
155 0.00026161740
156 0.00026273480
157 0.00025433740
158 0.00023190220
159 0.00032647420
160 0.00045536660
161 0.00059348430
162 0.00071511420
163 0.00067028920
164 0.00041854670
165 0.00006607927
166 0.00026329740
167 0.00035744760
168 0.00036180040
169 0.00042759340
170 0.00055509210
171 0.00080110420
172 0.00087520910
173 0.00058697610
174 0.00019995160
175 0.00006101286
176 0.00028858900
177 0.00084759000
178 0.00181664700
179 0.00241077300
180 0.00243060200
181 0.00229227800
182 0.00154039100
183 0.00066442720
184 0.00047923840
185 0.00053495560
186 0.00059540470
187 0.00082565970
188 0.00089290320
189 0.00068852520
190 0.00052633950
191 0.00045600620
192 0.00045093800
193 0.00031446380
194 0.00025688920
195 0.00050591460
196 0.00065890590
197 0.00075314030
198 0.00081628460
199 0.00076140250
200 0.00067777620
201 0.00054637950
202 0.00025384380
203 0.00017884110
204 0.00051058200
205 0.00069159130
206 0.00070856520
207 0.00076428450
208 0.00078698320
209 0.00075840920
210 0.00076780630
211 0.00070637800
212 0.00058991150
213 0.00043324860
214 0.00020571170
215 0.00013541920
216 0.00035493020
217 0.00065503070
218 0.00081393870
219 0.00070562180
220 0.00048681740
221 0.00028369840
222 0.00016386620
223 0.00017445290
224 0.00010558050
225 0.00025201070
226 0.00047917510
227 0.00054193000
228 0.00062080320
229 0.00075420800
230 0.00073815520
231 0.00068594600
232 0.00059341030
233 0.00048533430
234 0.00064485220
235 0.00093978680
236 0.00107734400
237 0.00100581900
238 0.00083295270
239 0.00077241650
240 0.00071219820
241 0.00052953920
242 0.00025131890
243 0.00007420720
244 0.00015245010
245 0.00025212410
246 0.00030551920
247 0.00036292530
248 0.00033049840
249 0.00021708740
250 0.00003483826
251 0.00015689240
252 0.00026166250
253 0.00042765080
254 0.00054671880
255 0.00048395470
256 0.00039395960
257 0.00032630420
258 0.00017592100
259 0.00011457660
260 0.00027027850
261 0.00027905040
262 0.00028964920
263 0.00026373080
264 0.00015361610
265 0.00015342390
266 0.00019579180
267 0.00009788586
268 0.00017791060
269 0.00033727830
270 0.00041148710
271 0.00036640740
272 0.00023879750
273 0.00015225990
274 0.00012894380
275 0.00016100280
276 0.00019511690
277 0.00028580940
278 0.00041538680
279 0.00048289850
280 0.00043793950
281 0.00054709280
282 0.00075454690
283 0.00072614030
284 0.00050950410
285 0.00047382490
286 0.00056846150
287 0.00056363520
288 0.00048822670
289 0.00029797660
290 0.00004850035
291 0.00023392300
292 0.00034054660
293 0.00041982740
294 0.00027621580
295 0.00016738640
296 0.00053438720
297 0.00246031200
298 0.00635195400
299 0.00872426700
300 0.00886001100
301 0.00842182000
302 0.00552294800
303 0.00187063100
304 0.00032508260
305 0.00016684410
306 0.00022078760
307 0.00021354370
308 0.00036864590
309 0.00029664110
310 0.00028277430
311 0.00044758820
312 0.00066086870
313 0.00068795020
314 0.00054706530
315 0.00038727160
316 0.00020979340
317 0.00023837620
318 0.00037146850
319 0.00046812860
320 0.00050758970
321 0.00046340350
322 0.00035557270
323 0.00035862050
324 0.00068795160
325 0.00102712300
326 0.00113426100
327 0.00111524500
328 0.00093137940
329 0.00064198000
330 0.00046677720
331 0.00034870680
332 0.00022170290
333 0.00020055940
334 0.00015228370
335 0.00033264600
336 0.00052374590
337 0.00059530440
338 0.00051557000
339 0.00035846670
340 0.00037672080
341 0.00040562270
342 0.00039243670
343 0.00070844400
344 0.00102321300
345 0.00103145200
346 0.00106949400
347 0.00097161720
348 0.00074078570
349 0.00059030840
350 0.00062849550
351 0.00058997010
352 0.00046812360
353 0.00039045500
354 0.00031880270
355 0.00028731090
356 0.00037539040
357 0.00039671140
358 0.00072463580
359 0.00104009000
360 0.00120817800
361 0.00120561800
362 0.00090148300
363 0.00056913190
364 0.00041829450
365 0.00050380050
366 0.00051382070
367 0.00043556910
368 0.00033269970
369 0.00006001350
370 0.00026658040
371 0.00025369280
372 0.00008696266
373 0.00016249120
374 0.00021243630
375 0.00017053970
376 0.00024295400
377 0.00044317500
378 0.00040772780
379 0.00031257840
380 0.00027488510
381 0.00024972680
382 0.00035150550
383 0.00053715380
384 0.00054458780
385 0.00030372910
386 0.00022779490
387 0.00027865900
388 0.00023653550
389 0.00012448450
390 0.00030496940
391 0.00046163470
392 0.00039380810
393 0.00019902760
394 0.00017711240
395 0.00039385040
396 0.00052798570
397 0.00061066690
398 0.00063706320
399 0.00057160660
400 0.00046064280
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=14cm,scaled y ticks=false,
    xtick={0,50,...,400},xmin=10,xmax=400,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=4},
    ymax = 0.010,ymin=0,
    %ymajorgrids,
    restrict y to domain = 0:0.01,
    no marks,
    extra x ticks = {60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360},
    extra x tick labels = {60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360},
    extra x tick style = {
        font = \tiny, 
        tick label style = {fill = blue!50, rotate = 45, anchor = west},
        grid = major,
        grid style={dotted, blue},
        },
    %axis line style={draw=none},
]
  \addplot[fill=cyan, opacity=.3] table {data2.dat} --(400,0)-- (0,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You already have extra ticks that are in filled box of a certain opacity. To make them equal size, use e.g. `tick label style = {fill = blue!50, rotate = 45, 
  anchor = west,text width=1em},`, i.e. add some universal `text width`. What else should be changed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.